# Computer Networks: how do packets find a computer in a network?

Tags: tcp, router, packet, lan, nat

Suppose I have a computer network, and all computers in this network have the same external IP. The network uses a NAT service to direct packets to specific computers in the network.

Let's say that one computer in the network sends a packet to a famous website. The packet includes the source IP, which is probably the external IP address and the destination IP (the IP of the website).

Now, the website returns a response to the external IP address of the network. My question is - once the response has reached the router of the network, how does it know to which computer in the network to send the response? All computers in the network have the same external IP.

Comment: No [tag:osi] here, only [tag:tcp-ip].

Answer (score 0):

the router do this with NAT Table.

[image: NAT Table]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all computers in the network have the same external IP address, but not the same port number. Different computers are mapped to different ports, and this is how the NAT knows how to direct the packet to the computer in the network. Am I right?

Comment: you should use PAT (Port Address Translation)                                                             192.168.1.1:1023 <-> 5.202.4.210:18234                                           192.168.1.2:1043 <-> 5.202.4.210:19243                                                                                                                               when a system need go to internet it use public ip address with port identifier and router with this table has been known every system behind private network and flow the packets based on its NAT (PAT) Table